# How to make a sky environment map?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

If I have a scene that I want to add a bounding box to that makes it look like it is outside during the day. In the past I have just added a big UV Sphere to my scene that surrounds the entire scene and added a texture that looks like a sky. This is a bit clunky and it can appear that the sky is too close and it makes it look fake.

Is there a better way for me to create a background for my scene? Is it possible to make an environment map for the sky? I am using the default Blender renderer.

Comment: Are we in Cycles? BI?

Comment: I feel to vote to close this, but if you can at least add a screenshot, maybe we can keep it open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add an image as your world background, you need to set that image as a texture input for the world object. To do this, add a texture to the world by selecting the world object in the Outliner, then selecting the 'Textures' tab of the Properties panel and adding a new texture. Go to the Preview submenu and select the world tab, so that you are editing the global texture. Finally, under the type of texture, select 'Image or Movie', and select the image you wish to use.

For a more detailed description of the subject, go to http://pages.uoregon.edu/art3d/composite/composite25.html.

Comment: Hi Gwenn, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: (My above comment is autogenerated by a userscript btw - your answer is good but could be better if you include the details from the link).

Comment: @RolandiXor I restated the essential points of it, but the link has a more tutorial-style format for readers interested in a greater level of detail.

Comment: Thank you Gwenn! I think this is a great solution. Thank you for cleaning up my question as well.

Comment: Generally I find when  using an equirectangular environment map, I have to enable "Real Sky" in the world settings, select "Equirectangular" mapping coordinates for the texture and also enable Horizon in the influence panel (so Blend and Horizon are on 1).

Comment: @Gwenn the linked page on the answer is gone.