# How to set an image as background in blender's internal render engine

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am not an very well experienced person in blender. I know how to set an image as background in cycles but how do I do it in blender render. 
<s>There is no answer in this topic all over the internet</s>. Please help.

Comment: If you mean using an image as environment for the world: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268/how-to-make-a-sky-environment-map

Comment: If you mean an image that is combined with the scene at render time: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode

Comment: If you mean an image as background to use as reference for modieling on the viewport: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing